# Monacaによるハイブリットアプリ制作にてFileTransferのUploadでFTP送信できない。

Tags: javascript, monaca, cordova

Monacaを使用して、Android及びiOS向けのハイブリッドアプリを制作しています。 
端末上のファイルを任意のFTPサーバーにアップロードしたいと思っております。 
CordovaプラグインでFileTransferプラグインをインストールし、以下のコードでアップロードしようとしています。

```
var win = function(r) { 
        alert("Success"); 
        } 

var fail = function(error) { 
        alert("failed"); 
        console.log("upload error code " + error.code); 
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source); 
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target); 
        } 

function hoge(){ 
        var options = new FileUploadOptions; 
        options.fileKey="file"; 
        options.fileName="myphoto.jpg"; 
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg"; 
        var params = {}; 
        params.value1 = "ftpid"; //FTPサーバーID 
        params.value2 = "ftppassword"; //FTPサーバーPass 
        options.params = params; 

        var ft = new FileTransfer(); 
        var path = "/sdcard/"+'monaca.jpg'; 
        ft.upload(path, encodeURI("ftp.server.url.com"), win, fail, options); 
    }
```

ファイルは端末の/sdcard/直下に配置しております。 
このft.uploadのところで失敗しているようですが、上記のfailで出力されるlogでは、

```
upload error code null 
upload error source null 
upload error target null
```

と表示され内容がわかりません。

デバッグ環境は
実機：NEXUS5
Androidバージョン： 5.1.1
Cordovaバージョン: 4.1.0
FileTransferバージョン：0.4.8

どなたかご教授願えないでしょうか

Comment: `var options = new FileUploadOptions`の末尾に`()`が抜けているようなのでまずこれを直してみてください

Comment: cither様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の点修正しましたが、結果は同じでした。

Comment: あ、失礼。コンストラクタの括弧は省略できるのでした。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決いたしました。
ft.upload(path, encodeURI("ftp.server.url.com"), win, fail, options); 
の、ftpサーバーの指定の部分がまずかったようです。
FileTransferのupload関数ではFTPに直接ファイルをアップロードできませんでした。
サーバーにファイル保存用のphpを置き、そのphpファイルをURLで指定することで解決しました。
結果次のようなコードにしました

```
ft.upload(path, encodeURI("http://server.url.com/receive.php"), win, fail, options);
```